# ng-click inside bs-tooltip not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I'm using [angular-strap tooltip](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/#tooltips) and inside I have link that should react to `ng-click`, but instead it's not responding.

**.html**

```
<span class="add-on input-group-addon" data-title="{{tooltips.date}}" bs-tooltip>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i> Dates
</span>
```

**.js**

```
$scope.tooltips = {
  date: '<a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="select()">Select date</a>'
};

$scope.select = function() {
  //doing something and works fine outside tooltip
}
```

In app `.config()` there is `html` set to `true`.

```
angular.extend($tooltipProvider.defaults, {
  template: "static/lib/angular-strap/tooltip.tpl.html",
  trigger: 'click',
  html: true,
  placement: 'bottom-left'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using data-title along with html: true you are just passing some html, but it is not compiled by angular. If you want to use angular directives and data binding in your tooltip, use 'contentTemplate'; here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/LSl9gyHRKCMYoEGZZQei