# Error displaying info on Tooltip with AngularStrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to display some info in a Tooltip and all I am getting is the Title like this
[image]

and here is my html where I call it

```
                    <button class="btn btn-primary"
                            type="button"
                            ng-click="moreInfoSlip(slip)"
                            data-trigger="click"
                            data-type="success"
                            data-title="{{tooltip.title}}"
                            bs-tooltip>
                            Click me
                    </button>
```

and here the JS

```
  $scope.moreInfoSlip = function(slip) {
    console.log(slip);
    $scope.tooltip = {
        title: '<strong>PICK INFO</strong>',
        content: '<div class="selection-info"><p><strong>Game</strong> ' + slip.gameLineObj.name + '</p>' +
        '<p><strong>League</strong> ' + slip.leagueObj.name + '</p>' +
        '<p><strong>Date</strong> ' + moment(slip.gameLineObj.date).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a') + '</p>' +
        '<p><strong>Line</strong> ' + _.result(_.find(slip.lines, {isSelected: '1'}), 'pick') + '</p></div>'
    };
  }
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `data-html="true"` attribute of tooltip. Like this

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"
                            type="button"
                            ng-click="moreInfoSlip(slip)"
                            data-trigger="click"
                            data-type="success"
                            data-html="true"
                            data-title="{{tooltip.title}}"
                            bs-tooltip>
                            Click me
                    </button>
```

Comment: still not displaying the content

Comment: You can try contentTemplate as said in this  answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23958094/3321784